# WHM & Cpanel cannot create database

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel, whm

I am running a new dedicated server with whm & cpanel 11.38. There is under 'Sql Services' options like 'Additional MySQL Access Hosts' and 'Repair a MySQL Database' but there are no icons to create a database. Also if going into phpmyadmin there is also no option to create a database.

It is my understanding that these icons should be there so how does one get them to appear or due to a software update is there another method that is supposed to be used to create a database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create databases from cPanel->PhpMyAdmin due to the lack of user privileges.
But you can do this from cPanel->MySQL Databases.

> cPanel->MySQL Databases->create database

Comment: Would you please explain. How may I get around this, If my PHP app wants to create databases on its own.

Comment: This is where you should make use of cPanel [API](http://forums.cpanel.net/f42/create-database-without-login-cpanel-130825.html) functions.

Comment: He He :) Happy New year 2014 #kamran