# Multiple Instances of XAMPP on an External Portable Harddisk

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp

Running Windows 11, 64 bit I need to install multiple instances of XAMPP on my external Hard disk. The drive will always be associated with the letter Z.

The purpose is to learn XAMPP including what the stack is made of i.e., Apache, MariaDB/MySQL, and PHP. Learning route is through various tutorials and online video courses such as:

[WordPress Full Course in ONE VIDEO | ZERO to HERO | STEP BY STEP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcbPVzq8lHY)

[How To Make A Digital Agency Website From Scratch In 2022 (WordPress And Elementor For Beginners)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sDJAIGVwV8)

These tutorials/courses asks to make projects such as the first is centered around "mywebsite" and the second is "jimakes". In order to do so I was thinking to have one installation of XAMPP at (I am using the Lab as the main folder in the drive Z)

```
Z:\Lab\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite
Z:\Lab\xampp\htdocs\jimakes
```

Now I will have 1 XAMPP installation and multiple WordPress installations (The WordPress installtions will be in each of the projects respective folders so that tinkering one WordPress installation does not effect the other).

The problem is following through the 2nd course/tutorial and installing the WordPress theme (jimakes), Astra, I came across problems that required me to change some settings in the .htaccess file and php.ini files which I messed up. This resulted in messing up the "mywebsite". This required me to uninstall everything and do a clean reinstall of XAMPP and WordPress. And that resulting in also removing the htdocs folder. (There is an option of not removing that folder during the uninstall process but I don't want to do that say just to be sure I have a clean reinstall with default settings).

Now I am thinking to have multiple XAMPP installations and a single WordPress installation such as

```
Z:\Lab\mywebsite\xampp\htdocs\PUBLIC_HTML
Z:\Lab\jimakes\xampp\htdocs\PUBLICC_HTML
```

The purpose is two fold. First I can happily chip away with messing everything up in one project and it won't effect the other. The second I am trying to replicate a real hosting live server from one of the server providers such as Go Daddy or Host Gator as much as possible so that migrating from the local development environment to the production one is as pain less as possible when I move on to real projects.

Now to cut the story short and trying to catch the river in a cup I would ask

1. To create a exact replica of the hosting providers environment on a local development environment with the aim of firstly learning technologies such as PHP, MariaDB/MySQL, WordPress and later on exporting real life project from the local development to hosting environment with the confidence that all I need to do is move the files (FTP via FileZilla?). This cannot be achieved since if I am not wrong, one can never install cPanel locally. Secondly who has the time to consider in so many variables for example you cannot create a new database or user using phpMyAdmin in a hosting account but you can on a local environment.

[WHM & Cpanel cannot create database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846057/whm-cpanel-cannot-create-database)

2. What needs to be changed for once and once only. You will notice that I have changed the htdocs to PUBLIC_HTML as the root document folder (Is it same as the Server Folder?). The aim is to actually learn PHP and WordPress and MySQL without being bothered about why it's not working. I know why it's not working itself is an important part of learning but it just muddles the waters since your objective is to learn the technologies and not why it's not working (The why it's not working comes later, don't ask me why, I am too dumb to learn two things at a time).
3. I tried installing Apache, MySQL/MariaDB, and PHP manually without using XAMPP. This resulted in learning about more about installations and errors and how to fix them and blah blah blah rather than actually learning PHP, MariaDB/MySQL and WordPress. Exactly the thing that I was trying to avoid. Some would argue you cannot learn one without the other but I already have HTML and CSS under my belt (I know, I know, JavaScript, I will get there) and again the purpose is to move to the backend and save time by avoiding and worrying about how to fix them errors (took me two hours to figure out why my php manual installation was not working. Turns out one needs to set PATH in system environment variables in Windows 11)

[PHP Not Executable in Command Prompt Windows, Environment Variable is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68727401/php-not-executable-in-command-prompt-windows-environment-variable-is-set)

4. Why can't I just use a hosting provider production environment? Than why XAMPP is there?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of asks here, you shoould split them to individual asks, i Will help you with the Title Ask.

Is as common task have into dev environment many projects, but you can run all with a single instance and a single port, such as 80 in dev machine.

You can set Many **Virtual Hosts** so istead of use default http://localhost you can create a better host for each project, Eg:

http://project1.local
http://project2.local

and proceed with development with no pain, here a tutorial, teaching how you can create this env.

https://www.wdb24.com/how-to-setup-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp/